# Overflow-x:hidden is not working

Tags: iframe, scroll, hidden

I've been searching around this website on how to remove horizontal scroll bars through iframe, but no solution worked. Can anyone help please? Long story short, here is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://voipstatus.clanwarz.com/lib/serverstatus/ventrilo.php?ip=marble.servegame.com&port=3784&uncolor=999999&cncolor=999999&fgcolor=999999&bgcolor=181818&type=2&templateid=6&title=Marble%20(marble.info.tm%20/%203784)&width=250&hl=1&expanded=1&sT=0&size=10&jquery=1&showOnlyActive=0&pe=0" width="250" height="100%" style="border:none;overflow-x:hidden;" ></iframe>
```

As you can see, it's set on overflow-x:hidden, but the horizontal bar still shows.

My website is: www.marble.co.nr

Answer (score 0):

Add css style to this ifram

```
iframe html {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would that work? I mean where do I type this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found an alternative. Not exactly the way I wanted it to be, but it's still do-able. I had an iframe in my page. So instead, I put a replaced it with a blank iframe in that page and then added the Ventrilo server status iframe inside that blank iframe.

If that made any sense...